# How to search with multiple parameters in Hibernate Search 3.0.0.ga

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

Using:

- Hibernate 3.2.7.ga
- Hibernate-Search 3.0.0.ga
- Hibernate-Anotations 3.3.0.ga
- Hibernate-Commons-Cnnotations 3.0.0.ga
- Lucene-Core 2.9.4
- Lucene-Analyzers 2.9.4
- Lucene-Queryparser 2.9.4

How can search with multiple parameters like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM example 
WHERE column1 = "text1"
AND (column2 = "text2" OR column2 ="text3")
```

With [Hibernate-Search documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.0/reference/en/html_single/#d0e267) I only found that example of searching:

```
Session session = universalHibernateDAO.getHibernateSession();
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.createFullTextSession(session);

Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29,
    new String[]{"summary", "body"}, analyzer);
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = parser.parse( "Java rocks!" );
Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( query, PscpExpedient.class );
List<PscpExpedient> result = (List<PscpExpedient>)hibQuery.list();
      
tx.commit();
```

Will be perfect if exist some way to do something like:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = parser.parse("column1: text1", 
                                                      "column2: text2 | text3" );
```

Also, if that is possible, will be nice to know how search "onlyOneword" and "text with multiple spaces"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use BooleanQuery like this:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query1 = ....;
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query2 = ....;
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query3 = ....;

BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

luceneBooleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
luceneBooleanQuery.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
luceneBooleanQuery.add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD); 

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(booleanQuery, DomainClass.class);
```

It should work.

Comment: I'll try and ask something. Thanks for fast response.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot for your help ^.^